# Python sort using cmp_to_key does not swap some items

Tags: python, sorting

My program received a list to be sorted using "direct dependencies" passed as a `dict`. One must appear after other items it depends on.

I'm using `functools.cmp_to_key` to return `1` or `-1` when compared items depends on each other or `0` when they don't:

Here is my MCVE:

Dependencies definition:

```
def dependencies():
    return { "B" : ["A"], "C" : ["B","A"], "D" : ["C","B"] }
```

Comparison function:

```
def dependency_cmp(module_left, module_right):
    if module_right in dependencies() and module_left in dependencies()[module_right]:
        print( module_right + " needs " + module_left )
        return -1
    elif module_left in dependencies() and module_right in dependencies()[module_left]:
        print( module_left + " needs " + module_right )
        return 1
    else:
        print( module_left + " and " + module_right + " are independent" )
        return 0
```

Sort function:

```
def doSort( the_list ):
    original = the_list[:]
    the_list.sort(key=cmp_to_key(lambda left, right: dependency_cmp(left,right)))
    print( "Dependencies [" + ",".join(original) + "] sorted to [" + ",".join(the_list) + "]" )
```

Then, when I call:

```
doSort( ["C","D","B","A"] )
doSort( ["B","E","A"] )
```

It outputs:

```
D needs C
D needs B
D needs B
C needs B
C needs A
B needs A
Dependencies [C,D,B,A] sorted to [A,B,C,D]
```

which is correct, but:

```
E and B are independent
A and E are independent
Dependencies [B,E,A] sorted to [B,E,A]
```

which is not correct, I would expect the output to be `[A,B,E]` or `[E,A,B]` or `[A,E,B]` as `B` needs `A` and `E` does not need any...

But as `B`,`E` and `E`,`A` order is correct, sort function does not check `B` against `A`. It makes sense, but that's definitely not what I want. The problem is likely due to this `return 0`. I'm familiar with C++ where `sort` functions returns a boolean rather than an integer...

What would be the best strategy to order those lists correctly?

Comment: This is a [toposort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). The normal `sort` function is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Thanks! And this post apparently provides me with a working function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557241/python-sorting-a-dependency-list

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to Aran-Fey comment and using toposort code from [Python: sorting a dependency list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557241/python-sorting-a-dependency-list):

```
def topological_sort(source):
    """perform topo sort on elements.

    :arg source: list of ``(name, set(names of dependancies))`` pairs
    :returns: list of names, with dependancies listed first
    """
    pending = [(name, set(deps)) for name, deps in source]        
    emitted = []
    while pending:
        next_pending = []
        next_emitted = []
        for entry in pending:
            name, deps = entry
            deps.difference_update(set((name,)), emitted) # <-- pop self from dep, req Py2.6
            if deps:
                next_pending.append(entry)
            else:
                yield name
                emitted.append(name) # <-- not required, but preserves original order
                next_emitted.append(name)
        if not next_emitted:
            raise ValueError("cyclic dependancy detected: %s %r" % (name, (next_pending,)))
        pending = next_pending
        emitted = next_emitted
```

Then:

```
def doSort( the_list ):
    original = the_list[:]

    source = []
    for item in the_list:
        source.append( [ item, set( dependencies()[item] ) if item in dependencies() else set() ] )

    the_list = [x for x in topological_sort( source )]

    print( "Dependencies [" + ",".join(original) + "] sorted to [" + ",".join(the_list) + "]" )
```

And finally we get the expected output:

```
Dependencies [C,D,B,A] sorted to [A,B,C,D]
Dependencies [B,E,A] sorted to [E,A,B]
```